# Why does my JSON parse with some missing key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I have a Rails backend that would serve JSONs like this: (This e.g. is 2.json)

```
{"id":2,"name":"Magic","location":"Cyberjaya","surprise_type":"Great","instructions":"test","status":"awesome","pricing_level":3,"longitude":"2.90873","latitude":"101.655027","created_at":"2016-02-02T07:19:18.247Z","updated_at":"2016-02-02T12:59:14.403Z"}
```

and an AngularJS app.js code that goes like this (the relevant parts only):

```
.factory('MarkersLoc', function($resource) {
  debugger;
  return $resource("http://localhost:3000/surprises/:id.json");
})

.factory('Markers', function(MarkersLoc) {

  var markers = [];

  return {
    getMarkers: function(){
        return MarkersLoc.query().$promise.then(function(response){
          debugger;
          markers = response;
        console.log("Markers: ", markers);
          return markers;
      });

    }
  }
})
```

The problem that I'm having is that, even at the point of the debugger, response is an array of objects that have all the attributes from the JSON except longitude, latitude, created_at and updated_at.

Unfortunately I am unable to determine the reason why these four key-value pairs are omitted when it's being read and returned. Is there something that should be controlling which key-value pair is being processed that I have left out on? Wouldn't the entire JSON be parsed and converted into the object?

Comment: What is the JSON *sent to the browser*? It is unlikely that data will "disappear" when JSON-decoded if it is indeed part of the response.

Comment: Do you use a serializer in your _Rails_ application? Look for any file with a name similar to `*_serializer.rb`.

Comment: @user2864740 - Loading the json URL directly returned the above. Would it serve it differently to a browser as compared to what I would see if I went on the link to the json directly? (This being http://localhost:3000/surprises/2.json)

Comment: @gnerkus - 
I just looked and found on the Rails side  app/serializers/surprise_serializer.rb, with this code:

    `class SurpriseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer`
      `attributes :id, :name, :location, :surprise_type, :instructions, :status, :pricing_level`
    `end`

I will try changing this file and get back on if it is the cause of it

Comment: @JoelLim Use the Network Log/Monitor (in the Browser Developer Tools) to view what the client actually gets. Nothing else is immediately relevant until actual returned response has been verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing values are the result of the data being serialized by the controller on the backend. To view all the keys, ensure all the attributes are defined in the serializer:

```
class SurpriseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :name,
             :location,
             :surprise_type,
             :instructions,
             :status,
             :pricing_level,
             # Add the missing attributes to the serializer
             :longitude,
             :latitude,
             :created_at,
             :updated_at
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I did this and it worked. I totally forgot about this serializer and when I edited it the first time (if I did in the first place). This was indeed the solution, and it is so embarrassing that it was something so simple.